# How can we hold variable in entire aws step function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-glue, aws-step-functions, aws-marketplace

Actually My aws lambda returns some value, as you can see in the image.  I want access this value in last glue script as an input. Is there any way to use this value in last glue step? I have tried with resultpath and inputpath also but it's not working.

[image: 1]

Here I am trying to access lambda output values in last glue job for input:

[image: 2]

Comment: How is it not working? Please edit your question the actual and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

If you want data returned by your [Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) function in the first step of your [Step Functions Workflow](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) to be available in the 4th step of your workflow, you need to use [ResultPath](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-resultpath.html).

By default, the output of your 1st state will be the response from the Lambda invoke call. This will be passed into the second `Glue StartJobRun` state and the output of that state will be the response from that API call to [Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/glue/). In this case, the response from your 1st step will not be available in subsequent steps.

If you want to keep some of that state data, you use ResultPath in your 2nd step to place the response from the Glue call into a different node in your output and combine it with the Input to the state. You then keep doing this in subsequent steps to persist important data through the remainder of your workflow.